# Python microphone input and low pass filter effect realtime

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to use a raspberry pi to receive microphone input and add an effect outputting a low pass audio filter effect on the microphone input in real time. Their many python audio libraries out there like sonic pi  / py audio. If any one can help me on how to accomplish this .

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a raspberry pi , but I've tried something similar with python on windows. I am assuming you may be able to modify this program to suit your needs.

For this, you will need to  install [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)
`pip install pyaudio`

And `python sounddevice` that you can download from [here](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/)

This program:
Records audio from microphone
Limits audio with a limiter
Playbacks  modified audio
Plots both original and modified audio

### Python Code

```
from pyaudio import PyAudio, paContinue, paFloat32
from time import sleep
from numpy import array, random, arange, float32, float64, zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sounddevice as sd

################################### Constants ##################################

fs            = 44100   # Hz
threshold     = 0.8     # absolute gain
delay         = 40      # samples
signal_length = 1      # second
release_coeff = 0.5555  # release time factor
attack_coeff  = 0.5     # attack time factor
dtype         = float32 # default data type
block_length  = 1024    # samples

############################# Implementation of Limiter ########################

class Limiter:
    def __init__(self, attack_coeff, release_coeff, delay, dtype=float32):
        self.delay_index = 0
        self.envelope = 0
        self.gain = 1
        self.delay = delay
        self.delay_line = zeros(delay, dtype=dtype)
        self.release_coeff = release_coeff
        self.attack_coeff = attack_coeff

    def limit(self, signal, threshold):
        for i in arange(len(signal)):
            self.delay_line[self.delay_index] = signal[i]
            self.delay_index = (self.delay_index + 1) % self.delay

            # calculate an envelope of the signal
            self.envelope *= self.release_coeff
            self.envelope  = max(abs(signal[i]), self.envelope)

            # have self.gain go towards a desired limiter gain
            if self.envelope > threshold:
                target_gain = (1+threshold-self.envelope)
            else:
                target_gain = 1.0
            self.gain = ( self.gain*self.attack_coeff +
                          target_gain*(1-self.attack_coeff) )

            # limit the delayed signal
            signal[i] = self.delay_line[self.delay_index] * self.gain



################### Record Audio from Microphone #########################    

print "Recording Audio"
signal = sd.rec(signal_length * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=1, dtype=dtype)
sd.wait()
print "Audio recording complete , Play Audio"



################################# Play the Audio ###############################

original_signal = array(signal, copy=True, dtype=dtype)
limiter = Limiter(attack_coeff, release_coeff, delay, dtype)

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    if flag:
        print("Playback Error: %i" % flag)
    played_frames = callback.counter
    callback.counter += frame_count
    limiter.limit(signal[played_frames:callback.counter], threshold)
    return signal[played_frames:callback.counter], paContinue

callback.counter = 0

pa = PyAudio()

stream = pa.open(format = paFloat32,
                 channels = 1,
                 rate = fs,
                 frames_per_buffer = block_length,
                 output = True,
                 stream_callback = callback)

while stream.is_active():
    sleep(0.1)

stream.close()
pa.terminate()

############################## Plot results ####################################

plt.figure()
plt.plot(original_signal, color='green', label='original signal')
plt.plot(signal, color='red', label='limited signal')
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=True)
############################## End Program ####################################
```

### Terminal Output

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Recording Audio
Audio recording complete , Play Audio
>>>
```

### Image Output

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for response . pyaudio looks like the right solution need to see if it will work on raspberry pi. So the limiter is like a low pass filter is the resulting sound like a smattering or marbling effect? Any way many thanks.

Comment: Hello, If you are satisfied with the answer, then please select question as answered / closed.

Comment: Limiter reduced gain of signal during attack and release time periods.

Comment: I will be testing answer today and will close post son after. I might have more information to update about the post before I close it thank. will let you know.

Comment: I have finally tried the suggested code above on the raspbeery pi. I am currently receiving the error import sounddevice as sd (ImportError: No module named sounddevice) . When I check in python command line Iusing help(modules) to view installed modules sounddevice seems to be they. But the error keeps persisting hope you can help. Thank you.

Comment: can you check - 1) if it shows `soundddevice` installed by running equivalent of `pip install sounddevice` ?.   2) If needed you can run `pip install sounddevice --upgrade`  to upgrade existing modules. 3) check if you have sounddevice.py in the Python_folder\Lib\site-packages. 4) Add sounddevice.py path to PYTHONPATH 5) Try calling sounddevice explicitly using its path. For (5) you can search stackoverflow with keyword "how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path"

Comment: Hello I solve that problem. Solution is to pip install sounddevice  exclude the --user as should on the documentation. Now the error appearing is Playback : Error 4. If you know any solution to this please help.

Comment: Can u post ur code ? I will see if I can replicate.

Comment: Hi. Thanks you for the reply. The code is above with the plotting functions removed. Hope you can try it and see. Thanks.

Comment: HI Anil . What platform are you running your code. I am using a raspberry pi .2 and 3.

Comment: Windows 2010 and Python 2.7. I suggest to check the code on PC. before running on PI.